# angularjs using ng-resource to node.js back-end not sending correct POST request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ngresource

I would like to make a POST request to my node.js server (using express) from my angularjs app. I'm having troubles to send the correct {key:value}. Despite hours on researching the solution, I don't know how to write correctly the params to get them back on the server side . My results is : **'{"key":"value"}': ''**. Where am I wrong ?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

**client.js**

```
module.factory("Friends", function($resource) {
return $resource("https://myUrl/:id", {'id': '@id'} ,{
    mes: {method: 'POST', headers: {'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} , isArray : false }
});
});

module.controller('communityCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Friends', function($scope,$rootScope, Friends) {
var value = "aValue";

$scope.getData = function()
{
    Friends.mes({id: 'jb'}, {key : 'value'} ).$promise.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });
}
}]);
```

**server.js**

```
app.post('myUrl/jb', function(req, res) {
console.log("req.body : ", req.body);
res.json({code: 0, message: req.body.msg || ""}); 
});
```

**output**

```
 req.body :  { '{"key":"value"}': '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $http?

Factory definition:

```
module
  .factory('friendsFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
      post: function (id, data) {
        return $http.post('https://myUrl/' + id, data);
      },
      get: function () {
        return $http.get('https://myUrl/');
      }
    };
  }]);
```

From within your controller:

```
module
  .controller('friendsController', ['friendsFactory', function (friendsFactory) {
    friendsFactory.post(1, {id: 1})
      .then(function (res) {
        // success
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        // there has been an error
        console.error(err.data);
      });
  }]);
```

Within your node.js API endpoint, req.body will either be a string, or an object.

Note: if it is a string, ensure that you are using the body-parser middleware on express.

On the node server:

```
var express = require('express')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});
```

The body-parser middleware (amongst other things) takes the payload in req.body and replaces it a valid java object representation of that data.

Comment: Hi @gavin , thank you for your answer, it works but I want to use $resource and not $http in order to perform theses requests.  Any idea about it ?

Comment: I've re-answered the question - which should hopefully fix your error and provide a small example of $resource working.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Your problem**

The issue you have in your code is likely the following line:

```
Friends.mes({id: 'jb'}, {key : 'value'} ).$promise.then(function(data){
```

Try changing it to:

```
Friends.mes({id: 'jb', key: 'value'}).$promise.then(function(data){
```

Once you've done this, the req.body object on the server route will contain the following `{id: 'jb', key: 'value'}` instead of `{ '{"key":"value"}': '' }`.

**Example $resource application:**

I've created a small example of using $resource to GET and POST to an API.

**./public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="friendController as vm">
    <div>
      {{vm.friend}}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="vm.getFriend()">Get User</button>
    <button ng-show="vm.friend" ng-click="vm.messageFriend(vm.friend)">Message Friend</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**./public/script.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

.factory('friendFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(
    '/api/v1/friends/:id',
    {id: '@_id'},
    {
      mes: {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        isArray : false,
        params: { message: true }
      }
    }
  );
}])

.controller('friendController', ['friendFactory', function (friendFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.friend = null;
  vm.getFriend = _getFriend;
  vm.messageFriend = _messageFriend;

  function _getFriend() {
    friendFactory.get({id: 1})
      .$promise
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        vm.friend = res;
      });
  }

  function _messageFriend(friend) {

    /* method 1: call $mes on a friend object: */

    // vm.friend.$mes({message: 'A message'})
    //   .then(function (friend) {
    //     vm.friend = friend;
    //   });

    /* method 2: call mes on the resource: */

    friendFactory.mes({_id: 1, message: 'A message'})
      .$promise
      .then(function (friend) {
        vm.friend = friend;
      });
  }

}]);
```

**index.js - the node.js server hosting the page and exposing a simple api**

```
var express = require('express')
  , path = require('path')
  , app = express()
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

var friends = [
  { _id: 0, name: 'A' },
  { _id: 1, name: 'B' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'C' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'D' }
];

app.get('/api/v1/friends', function (req, res) {
  return res.send(friends);
});

app.get('/api/v1/friends/:id', function (req, res) {
  for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    if (friends[i]._id == req.params.id) return res.send(friends[i]);
  }
  return res.status(404).send('Not found');
});

app.post('/api/v1/friends/:id', function (req, res) {
  for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    if (friends[i]._id == req.params.id) {
      friends[i].message = req.query.message;
      return res.send(friends[i]);
    }
  }
  return res.status(404).send('Not found');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server running');
});
```

This example has a simple API that allows you to

1. GET a list of friends
2. GET a single friend
3. POST a message to a friend (I am assuming this is what your *mes* stands for?). When posting - `message` will be available as a querystring parameter (`req.query.message`) or in the body (`req.body.message`).

In this example, it simple appends 'message' to the friend and returns the object.

Things to note (In `friendController`): 
Calling `$mes` on an **existing** friend object returns a promise by default, so no need to chain `.$promise`.

Calling `mes` on the resource itself **does not** return a promise, so `$promise` is required.

Comment: Hi @gavin, thank you for your time, really appreciated. Unfortunalty, I still have my req.body issue : { '{"key":value}': '' } with the modification you gave me. Strange stuff : I sent a request with postman and it works properly, but it doesn't with my code. So i don't think it is a node.js problem. What code line should I show you ?

Comment: odd, can you console.log(req.body) and console.log(req.query) on the server and see what you have?